# Jquery function to make multiple dependent dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used the following code to run the following 2 dependent drop down list. Its working fine. Now I want to add 2 more fields namely Block and Hospital and all should be simultaneously dependent on the choice of the District. i.e If I change District then options of Subdivision, Block and Hospital should be filtered simultaneously. How should I change the jquery function.

```
$(function(){

var $cat = $("#cat"),
    $subcat = $("#subcat");     

$cat.on("change",function(){
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
    $subcat.val("");
    if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
    $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
    $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
});
});





District: <select name="dis"  id="cat" required><option></option><option 
>North </option><option >Unakoti</option></select>


Subdivision: <select name="subd" id="subcat"   required><option></option>
 <option rel="North" value="Dharmanagar">Dharmanagar</option>
 <option rel="North" value="Panisagar">Panisagar</option>
 <option rel="North" value="Kanchanpur">Kanchanpur</option>
 <option  rel="Unakoti" value="Kailasahar">Kailasahar</option>
   <option  rel="Unakoti" value="Kumarghat" >Kumarghat</option>
 </select> 

 //---------------------------------------------------

  Block: <select name="block" id="subcat1"   required><option></option>
 <option rel="North" value="a">a</option>
 <option rel="North" value="b">b</option>
 <option rel="North" value="c">c</option>
 <option  rel="Unakoti" value="d">d</option>
   <option  rel="Unakoti" value="e" >e</option>
 </select> 


 Hospital: <select name="hosp" id="subcat2"   required><option></option>
 <option rel="North" value="a1">a1</option>
 <option rel="North" value="b1">b1</option>
 <option rel="North" value="c1">c1</option>
 <option  rel="Unakoti" value="d1">d1</option>
   <option  rel="Unakoti" value="e1" >e1</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing now?

Comment: Only subdivision is changing with District. I want Subdivision, Block and Hospital all 3 should change with District.

Comment: i answered your question please check is that you wanted?

Comment: the term is called `chained select` google it, plenty of good data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this you wanted? i modified you logic. Just use `css` instead `attr`

```js
$(function(){

var $cat = $("#cat"),
    $subcat = $("#subcat");     
    $subcat1 = $("#subcat1");
    $subcat2 = $("#subcat2");
$cat.on("change",function(){
    var _rel = $(this).val();
    $subcat1.val('');
    $subcat2.val('');
    $subcat.val('');
    
    $subcat.find("option").css("display","none");
    $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
    $subcat1.find("option").css("display","none");
    $subcat1.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
    $subcat2.find("option").css("display","none");
    $subcat2.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
   
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
District: <select name="dis"  id="cat" required><option></option><option 
>North </option><option >Unakoti</option></select>


Subdivision: <select name="subd" id="subcat"   required><option></option>
 <option rel="North" value="Dharmanagar">Dharmanagar</option>
 <option rel="North" value="Panisagar">Panisagar</option>
 <option rel="North" value="Kanchanpur">Kanchanpur</option>
 <option  rel="Unakoti" value="Kailasahar">Kailasahar</option>
   <option  rel="Unakoti" value="Kumarghat" >Kumarghat</option>
 </select> 

  Block: <select name="block" id="subcat1"   required><option></option>
 <option rel="North" value="a">a</option>
 <option rel="North" value="b">b</option>
 <option rel="North" value="c">c</option>
 <option  rel="Unakoti" value="d">d</option>
   <option  rel="Unakoti" value="e" >e</option>
 </select> 


 Hospital: <select name="hosp" id="subcat2"   required><option></option>
 <option rel="North" value="a1">a1</option>
 <option rel="North" value="b1">b1</option>
 <option rel="North" value="c1">c1</option>
 <option  rel="Unakoti" value="d1">d1</option>
   <option  rel="Unakoti" value="e1" >e1</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Thank u. I have one more problem. I want to add two more fields say Gender (id=cat7, options say M, F)  and Dress (id=subcat7, options sat 1, 2 for M and 3, 4 for F) . They are completely independent of the previous fields,  Dress depends on Gender only. But I want to use them in the same page. How to modify the function, or we need to use another function.

Comment: write one change listener for gender and change dress based on gender. Logic will be the same as above answer